# google places.Autocomplete setting language

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to set language to en while using places.Autocomplete API. Below is the snippet I am using

```
var autoAddr = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete((document.getElementById('autocomplete')),{componentRestrictions: {country: 'IN'}}); 


google.maps.event.addListener(autoAddr, 'place_changed', function() {
var place = autoAddr.getPlace();
```

Here place.address_components' locality is returning the locality(city) in native language (Hindi) and rest of the parameters like administrative_area_level_1(state) etc are returned in English. I would like all the params to return in english.

Any thoughts please let me know

Prem

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&language=en">
</script>
```